# elasticsearch documents missing in the new index created from existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing index named "prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-03" and created new index named "PUT /prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-04-19"

Executed below commands in the same order.
PUT /prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-04-19

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "prod.custom.historical.tasks-2021-03"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "prod.custom.historical.tasks-2021-04-19"
  }
}

GET /prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-03/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "projectId": [
              "73ef9fa8-6665-4cbb-881c-4663030a7d45"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
"took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 93,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [


GET /prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-04-19/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "projectId": [
              "73ef9fa8-6665-4cbb-881c-4663030a7d45"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Which clearly indicates that there are missing documents, someone can please help me to understand the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reindex API, only the documents are copied from one index to another. You need to configure the mapping of the new index, as mentioned in the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

> The destination should be configured as wanted before calling
> _reindex. Reindex does not copy the settings from the source or its associated template.
>
> Mappings, shard counts, replicas, and so on must be configured ahead
> of time.

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping for the index `"prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-04-19"`  then you need to add .keyword to the `projectId` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `projectId` field).

```
GET /prod.dhl.historical.actions-2021-04-19/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "projectId.keyword": [            // note this
              "73ef9fa8-6665-4cbb-881c-4663030a7d45"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Applied the changes, but same issue.

Comment: @SunilYerra can you share the index mapping of your new index for the particular field `projectId`? Have you explicitly set any index mapping of the new index ?

Comment: @SunilYerra and can you please confirm whether the documents are indexed in the new index by hitting the match_all query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html

Comment: I m new to this technology and honestly speaking donot know how to retrieve the mapping for the new index

Comment: GET /prod.custom.historical.actions-2021-04-19/_mapping is this what i need to execute

Comment: @SunilYerra yes, on hitting the GET mapping API --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html, you will get the mapping of the index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231315/discussion-between-escoder-and-sunil-yerra).

Comment: "projectId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },

Comment: thanks for the quick help, the problem was while creating the new index, I did not map the filelds as per the old index.